# Anybody use Nagios in conjunction with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nagios, datastax-enterprise, datastax

There seem to be multiple plugins written for monitoring cluster nodes with Nagios, however I run into the same problem with each one.

Basically, if I run the plugin script locally from the Cassandra node, it gives me the correct number of nodes that are up and healthy.

However if I try to run the command remotely from the non-Cassandra node/Nagios Server, you have to use NRPE and no matter what using nrpe_check always returns that there are 0 nodes up and running.

I "think" this has to be some sort of issue with NRPE being unable to use the nodetool command (since the plugins require nodetool to check status), however I have yet to be able to figure it out.  I've even tried running the NRPE command (nrpe_check) locally on the Cassandra node using the datastax/Cassandra user, and it still tells me there are zero nodes running.

I couldn't find anything helpful via googling, I'm guessing maybe many folks don't bother and just use OpsCenter alarms but we have problems with OpsCenter taxing our cluster and causing other issues so most of the time it's not running.

Answer (score -1):

you should try installing opscenter in another host (outside the cluster), it does all the monitoring pretty good and really helps a lot with configurations, rebalancing and modifications to the cluster.

with their latest release of Opscenter 5.1.1 a lot of issues where fixed including the new backup system